# Wants to show my article title inside <title> tag in node.js express

Tags: node.js, express

In my node.js application http://comeoutloud.com/, I have common header for all pages. I want to display my article title inside title tag, so we can have different title for each article.

Currently I am showing like this:

```
<title>{{title}}</title>
```

but this is showing full article title for each page.

Following query send the details of article to articlepage.

```
var articledetailpage = function (req, res, next) {
 async.parallel({     
    similararticle: function(callback){ 
                        var query=Articlepost.find({status:true,content_category:req.query.type}).sort({"_id":-1}).where("_id").ne(req.query.id);
                        query.exec(function(err,lv){
                          callback(null,lv);
                        });
                },
  quriedarticle: function (cb){                             
                           var query=Articlepost.findOne({_id:req.query.id,status:true});
                           query.exec(function(err,status){
                            cb(null,status);
                         });                          
 },
}, function (error, results) { 
  /*console.log(results);*/
   res.locals.title=results.quriedarticle.title;
   console.log(res.locals.title);
  res.write(loadView('articledetail',{morecontent:results.similararticle, queried:results.quriedarticle,type:req.query.type}));
  next();
});
 };                                                                  
app.get('/articlepage',header,headerhome,articledetailpage,sidebarvideogallery,footer);
```

I am calling header page like this..in which title tag is present.

```
 var headerhome = function (req, res, next) {
 var cont=loadView('headerhomepage')
  res.write(cont);
  next();
  };
```

Any idea how to implement will be appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide code you are using for showing title? So then we could modify it for you.

Comment: Let's say it looks like this: `app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.html', {title=article.title});});`

Comment: @KamilWozniak: Please see the edit.

Comment: thanks, I am looking at it right now. Please ignore my answer for now.

Comment: Could you try changing this line: `res.write(loadView('articledetail',{morecontent:results.similararticle, queried:results.quriedarticle,type:req.query.type}));` into this: `res.write(loadView('articledetail',{morecontent:results.similararticle, queried:results.quriedarticle,type:req.query.type, title:results.quriedarticle.title}));` ? Or maybe the proper way to send title will be `#{title}`? How you are passing variables to view?

Comment: @KamilWozniak :app.get('/articlepage',header,headerhome,articledetailpage,sidebarvideogallery,footer); we are calling our template in divided section , thus header template is before article detail , defining title in articledetail function will not modify title in head in that way you have suggested, We already tried that.

Comment: I need to see your layout template, `res.locals.title=results.quriedarticle.title;` should provide proper title, but it seems that `{{title}}` is not showing it. I know many different ways of displaying, like: just `title`, `<% title %>`, `{{title}}`, `#{title}`. Could you change a way you are displaying title?

Comment: @KamilWozniak: I am using handlebar template for frontend. Just tried all different ways you have given but not get the desired result.

Comment: Please, for reference see this page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars-layouts it explains how to use handlebars-layouts.